# File splitting using python

Tags: python, file, csv

```
import csv
import os
mycsv =csv.reader(open("IF_1027_SampleFile.csv","r"))
mycsv1 =csv.reader(open("Output","a"))
search_query ='Record Detail'
line =mycsv.readline()
if line==Searchquery:
    mycsv1.write(line)
    line =mycsv.readline()
else
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

Now I am getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: ("mismatched input 'mycsv1' expecting INDENT", ('<string>', 9, 0, 'mycsv1.write(line)\n'))
```

Can you help me on this. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses.  Change the semicolons `;` to closing parentheses `)`.  There should be no semicolons.  Your indentation is also broken.

Comment: I have fixed your code. Can you verify if you still have the issue?

Comment: are you trying to write all the lines after the Searchquery or just one line?

Comment: Also please show sample data

Comment: now i am getting errors after changes also..here i the error i am getting                                                        SyntaxError: ("mismatched input 'mycsv1' expecting INDENT", ('<string>', 9, 0, 'mycsv1.write(line)\n'))

Comment: have you properly indented those lines?

Comment: @astrosyam I want to read all lines after search query. so please help me on this

Comment: Please edit the code in the question. Don't post it in comments.

Comment: sorry for the inconvience @TheGeorgeous .. i already edited code in the question itself..

Comment: @astrosyam sample data will be like                                                  Record Header       col1,col2,col3                                                                              Record deatil           col1,col2,col3,col4,col5

Comment: ok based on your previous comment, I assume that you want to copy all rows in the file which start with Record detail . You should put sample data and expected output in the question so that people can help solve the issue..

Comment: please help me on this how to separate those columns record detail ...can u please let me know where i am doing mistake..

Comment: Your error message was caused by different code  than the one shown.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure about your expected output.

Based on your comment , I assume the following :

**INPUT FILE** 
- Sample data

```
record header               
col1    col2    col3        
1              2       3        
2              3       4        
Record Detail               
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
1           2      3        4       5
2           3      4        5       6
```

**Expected ouput** 
All rows after record detail.

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
    1      2       3       4       5
    2      3       4       5       6
```

**Code**

Since there were a few issues with the original code, I have written a simplified version below :

```
outfile = open('Output','a')

Searchquery = 'Record Detail'
flag = 0

with open('IF_1027_SampleFile.csv','r') as infile:
    for row in infile:
        if ( not flag):
            if Searchquery in row:            #checks for Searchquery
                flag = 1                      #raises flag
        else:
            outfile.write(row)                #if flag is 1, then write to file


outfile.close()
```

The code opens the input file, checks each row for the Search Query and writes rows after the Search Query to the output file.

Comment: my sample file will be                                                                                                    record header    col1,col2,col3
                              1, 2, 3
                              2,3,4
                              4,5,6
record detail    col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
                          1,2,3,4,5
                           2,3,4,5,6                                                                               Now i need to separate all columns and data under record header .please help me on this.. @astrosyam

Comment: my requirement here is under record header i will have columns and data continuously and record detail will start under that will have some more columns and corresponding data.... @astrosyam

Comment: in future, please try and post the expected result as a table in the question.

Comment: i am getting the below error after using the above logic                                                                                                      ("mismatched input '' expecting EOF", ('<string>', 8, 4, '    for row in infile:\n'))                                                                                                            can  u please help me on this @astrosyam

Comment: check your indentation! make sure the spaces and tabs are exactly as above. Python is sensitive to white spaces. It seems to be working for me...

Comment: for me it is telling like "with" is a reserved keyword. so, i imported "from__ future__ import with_statement".    But still i am getting error like  "from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file".  can u please help me on this @astrosyam

Comment: thank u for helping me on this..now it is working fine @astrosyam

Comment: great, please upvote or accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: And one more question i have... at a time i want to separate records under "record header" and "record detail" into two different files .... is it possible??... if possible can u please provide me the solution ??   @astrosyam

Comment: can u please help me on this @astrosyam

Comment: you probably just need to open another file for output and put write(row) in  the if block which checks the flag

Comment: not able to get it..can u please explain me with code...sorry for troubling u so much...please help me with code @astrosyam

Comment: please help me on this ...i am not able to do this... can u please help me through coding.. @astrosyam